# JAVA - creating an Array List in main method and using it in other classes without recreating it

Tags: java

So this is my array in Main method:

```
ArrayList<String> myarray = new ArrayList<>();
while(scan.hasNextLine()){
    myarray.add(scan.nextLine());
}
scan.close();
```

My application has multiple threads and I'm trying to use this array (which is kind of huge) in every thread without re-creating the array each time.
The main idea is to have it loaded in some way and ready to be called by other classes.

Comment: Just assign it to a class member, and create a public getter to it. Then you can use the array from anywhere. You might want to synchronize it if we're talking threads.

Comment: Can you elaborate your question. One thing ArrayList is not thread safe and should not be used when multiple threading are accessing it.

Comment: What about accessing this arraylist using a synchronized singleton object

Answer (score 0):

May be the below gives you some idea

```
class Myclass{
    private ArrayList<String> myarray = new ArrayList<>();
    main(){
        //populate the array
    } 
    public ArrayList<String> getList(){
        return myarray;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Following SHG suggestion:

```
public MyStaticClass {
    // from your question is not clear whether you need a static or non static List
    // I will assume a static variable is ok
    // the right-hand member should be enough to synchornize your ArrayList
    public static List<String> myarray = Collections.synchronizedList(new ArrayList<String>());

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // your stuff (which contains scanner initialization?)

        ArrayList<String> myarray = new ArrayList<>();
        while(scan.hasNextLine()){
            myarray.add(scan.nextLine());
        }
        scan.close();

        // your stuff (which contains thread initialization?)
    }
```

but if you really need a non-static variable

```
public MyClass {

    private final List<String> myarray;

    public MyClass() {
        // the right-hand member should be enough to synchornize your ArrayList
        myarray = Collections.synchronizedList(new ArrayList<String>());
    }

    public void getArray() {
        return myarray;
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // your stuff (which contains scanner initialization?)

        Myclass myObj = new MyClass();
        List<String> myObjArray = myObj.getArray();
        while(scan.hasNextLine()){
            myObjArray.add(scan.nextLine());
        }
        scan.close();

        // your stuff (which contains thread initialization?)
    }
```

For details about static vs non-static fields have a look at [Oracle documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/classvars.html) (basically, you will, or will not, need a `MyClass` instance to get `myarray` access but you will, or will not, be able to have different lists within your JVM).